# Saving PDF file slow after 10,000 pages in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, wpf, itext

I am trying to build a application that creates PDF and saves in local file. I am using this through iTextSharp in C#. I need to save at least 100 000 PDF files.

After 10 000 files the saving gets slow. The first 10k gets saved in 2 mins, rest of the files take almost 5 hours.

I believe the issue is usage of memory. But I could not find a solution to fix that issue. I have posted the source code.

```
private void CreatePDF11()
{
    Queue<String> QTempFileNames;
    QTempFileNames = new Queue<string>();
    string fileName = string.Empty;

    DateTime fileCreationDatetime = DateTime.Now;

    fileName = @"D:\StatementMassPrint\tesystw14j414435.PDF";

    string DestinationDirectory = @"D:\StatementMassPrint";

    string StrTempFilePath = String.Empty;

    string pdfPath = fileName;

    int TempPdfFileName = 1;
    if (DestinationDirectory != string.Empty)
    {
        StrTempFilePath = DestinationDirectory + "temp" + "(" + DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() + ")";
    }

    if (!(Directory.Exists(StrTempFilePath)))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(StrTempFilePath);
    }
        string reportFileName = StrTempFilePath + "\\" + TempPdfFileName.ToString() + ".Pdf";

        for (int f = 0; f < 100000; f++)
        {
            reportFileName = StrTempFilePath + "\\" + TempPdfFileName.ToString() + ".Pdf";

            using (FileStream msReport = new FileStream(reportFileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        //step 1
        using (Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A5.Rotate(), 10f, 10f, 200f,40f))
        {
            try
            {
                // step 2
                PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, msReport);
                pdfWriter.PageEvent = new EpisodePageHeaderAndFooter();

                //open the stream 
                pdfDoc.Open();

                DataTable dtEpisodeWise = new DataTable();
                dtEpisodeWise.Columns.Add("INVOICE_NO");
                dtEpisodeWise.Columns.Add("INVOICE_DATE");
                dtEpisodeWise.Columns.Add("CODE");
                dtEpisodeWise.Columns.Add("SERVICE_DESCRIPTION");
                dtEpisodeWise.Columns.Add("QTY",typeof(decimal));
                dtEpisodeWise.Columns.Add("UNIT_PRICE",typeof(decimal));
                dtEpisodeWise.Columns.Add("GROSS",typeof(decimal));
                dtEpisodeWise.Columns.Add("DISCOUNT",typeof(decimal));
                dtEpisodeWise.Columns.Add("NET",typeof(decimal));
                dtEpisodeWise.Columns.Add("DEDUCTION",typeof(decimal));
                dtEpisodeWise.Columns.Add("NET_PAYABLE_WITHOUT_VAT",typeof(decimal));
                dtEpisodeWise.Columns.Add("VAT",typeof(decimal));
                dtEpisodeWise.Columns.Add("NET_PAYABLE_WITH_VAT",typeof(decimal));

                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dtEpisodeWise.Columns.Count);
                table.WidthPercentage = 100;

                Font fontH1 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 6, Font.BOLDITALIC);
                for (int k = 0; k < dtEpisodeWise.Columns.Count; k++)
                {

                    string str = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(dtEpisodeWise.Columns[k].ColumnName.Replace("_", " ").ToLower()); ;
                    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(str,fontH1));
                    cell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
                    cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
                    //    cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(51, 102, 102);

                    table.AddCell(cell);
                }

             //   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
             //   {
                    dtEpisodeWise.Rows.Add("CR100005", "25-05-1989", "CPT004", "SERVICE005", 1, 10, 100, 10, 90, 45, 45, 5, 50);
                    dtEpisodeWise.Rows.Add("CR100006", "25-05-1992", "CPT00555", "SERVICE105",6, 60, 600, 60, 450, 45, 45, 5, 500);

             //   }

                Font fontH2 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 6, Font.ITALIC);

                for (int i = 0; i < dtEpisodeWise.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dtEpisodeWise.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {

                        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dtEpisodeWise.Rows[i][j].ToString(),fontH2));

                        //Align the cell in the center

                        if (dtEpisodeWise.Columns[j].DataType == typeof(decimal))
                        {
                            cell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_RIGHT;
                            cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT;
                            cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
                        }

                        table.HeaderRows = 1;

                        table.AddCell(cell);
                    }
                }
                    pdfDoc.Add(table);

                pdfDoc.Close();
                TempPdfFileName++;



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //handle exception
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Jeez, what do you need 10k of pages for? Nobody could ever possibly read this.

Comment: can you add to your question your source code so we can be able to identify the  issues

Comment: Has your system run out of RAM and started paging to disk?

Comment: @MatthewWatson this was my thought too. Would be god to see the code to offer some assistance!

Comment: @TiagoSilva  sure.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I am not sure. How to check this?

Comment: Why would you want to store this much data in a PDF file?
maybe consider using a more suitable file format?

Comment: @DenisSchaf I am doing this for research purspose. I believe PDF could do it as the first 10 k pages are getting saved wihin 2 minutes.

Comment: I have edited your question for clarification because nobody outside of India knows that 1 lakh or 1 lac = 100.000

Comment: Saving 10k pages in one go will be slow, no matter what code you use to save it. Even opening the file will take time. So you either put up with it or find another, more suited method of saving that much data. Perhaps a database with a simple front end will be better?

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Ok thank you.

Comment: One possible strategy: split up the work. You say that the first 10k pages are fast. Do it in batches of 10k pages, and then afterwards merge those files.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I need these many pages in 1 button click.

Comment: Yes and? You can still do that. Your button doesn't need to know the implementation details. Your button doesn't know or care if the file is written in one go, or first in several pieces that are then merged together.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I believe the issue is with system memory as the first 10 k saves easily. Is there any way to enhance the perfomance by using Garbage Collector or any sort of Disposal method.

Comment: calling GC here wont help you are already using the 'using' statement that its already closing the FileReader and the Document

Comment: @TiagoSilva okay

Comment: If your code is already working (albeit slow as you mentioned), then [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) would be a better fit for your question than stackoverflow

Comment: It is possible you don't get to the pdfDoc.Close() part, exiting the try block before that due to an exception, so it doesn't get freed up. Just a guess

Comment: For the rest, you are always creating the same datatable, the same font, why not extract that from the for loop? I guess the way you are currently filling your datatable is dummed down code, cause I'm not seeing why you would even need the database as you are always setting the same data in this sample. You should probably extract some more repeating code to some functions as well to maintain readability, but well these are points that could definitely be discussed in a review rather than on SO. Oh, and toss the try catch, who cares about the exceptions, let the program fail early

Comment: @Icepickle Ok thank you

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are a few things you aren't disposing of yet, which might cause the problem. For one, the `DataTable` implements `IDisposable` and so does the `PdfWriter`.

For the `PdfWriter`, you don't really need it as a variable declaration, as you are not really using it anyway, so you can just handle it like

```
using (PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, msReport))
{
    // ...
}
```

On thing to notice, is that you are currently recreating the fonts `fontH1` and `fontH2` at all times inside your for loop. I don't really see the need, they don't change during the entire run of your program, so you could declare them outside of your loop as local variables, or as part of a static field inside your class creating the pdf.

Another thing would be that you seem to recreate the same datatable over and over again, now I can assume that for your current code here, this is just dummy code, but from what I see, it's not necessary for you to create the datatable inside your loop, I rather think it could be an argument to create your pdf file (as would be the filename), so you could rewrite your code to create the pdf in its own class (I named it `PdfModule` but I'll bet there are lots better names for it :) ), and restructure your code to process 1 file at the time, like for example this:

```
public class PdfModule
{
    private static readonly Font H1Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 6, Font.BOLDITALIC);
    private static readonly Font H2Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 6, Font.ITALIC);

    public static void CreateFile(string filename, DataTable data)
    {
        using (var msReport = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (var pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A5.Rotate(), 10f, 10f, 200f, 40f))
            {
                using (PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, msReport))
                {
                    pdfDoc.Open();


                    var table = new PdfPTable(data.Columns.Count)
                    {
                        WidthPercentage = 100,
                        HeaderRows = 1
                    };
                    for (var k = 0; k < data.Columns.Count; k++)
                    {
                        var str =
                            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(data
                                .Columns[k].ColumnName.Replace("_", " ").ToLower());
                        ;
                        var cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(str, H1Font))
                        {
                            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                            VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
                        };

                        table.AddCell(cell);
                    }

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        for (var j = 0; j < data.Columns.Count; j++)
                        {
                            var cell =
                                new PdfPCell(new Phrase(data.Rows[i][j].ToString(), H2Font))
                                {
                                    VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                                    HorizontalAlignment = data.Columns[j].DataType == typeof(decimal)
                                        ? Element.ALIGN_RIGHT
                                        : Element.ALIGN_LEFT
                                };

                            table.AddCell(cell);
                        }
                    }

                    pdfDoc.Add(table);

                    pdfDoc.Close();
                }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

This would keep the font declaration as static fields on class level, so initializing them only once during the programs run, and would write 1 single file, with 1 single `DataTable` building up the document. Both are send as arguments.

To then use this class, I wrote the following sample code, and it seemed to generate the 100.000 files pretty fast (no where near the 5 hours you have mentioned).

Note that I do not have any details on how you are processing/filling the datatable in your real program, but at least it would give you a basic idea on how to restructure your code, and go from there

```
internal class Program
{
    private static DataTable CreateDataTable( IEnumerable<object[]> rawData )
    {
        var datatable = new DataTable();
        datatable.Columns.Add("INVOICE_NO");
        datatable.Columns.Add("INVOICE_DATE");
        datatable.Columns.Add("CODE");
        datatable.Columns.Add("SERVICE_DESCRIPTION");
        datatable.Columns.Add("QTY", typeof(decimal));
        datatable.Columns.Add("UNIT_PRICE", typeof(decimal));
        datatable.Columns.Add("GROSS", typeof(decimal));
        datatable.Columns.Add("DISCOUNT", typeof(decimal));
        datatable.Columns.Add("NET", typeof(decimal));
        datatable.Columns.Add("DEDUCTION", typeof(decimal));
        datatable.Columns.Add("NET_PAYABLE_WITHOUT_VAT", typeof(decimal));
        datatable.Columns.Add("VAT", typeof(decimal));
        datatable.Columns.Add("NET_PAYABLE_WITH_VAT", typeof(decimal));


        foreach (var row in rawData)
        {
            datatable.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return datatable;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rowData = new List<object[]>()
        {
            new object[] { "CR100005", "25-05-1989", "CPT004", "SERVICE005", 1, 10, 100, 10, 90,
                45, 45, 5, 50 },
            new object[] { "CR100006", "25-05-1992", "CPT00555", "SERVICE105", 6, 60, 600, 60,
            450, 45, 45, 5, 500 }
        };

        var pdfModule = new PdfModule();
        var outDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Output");
        if (!Directory.Exists(outDirectory))
        {
            // well theoretically I should just create the directory and worry about conflicts differently
            Directory.CreateDirectory(outDirectory);
        }

        Console.WriteLine( $"Creating files to {outDirectory}");
        var nrOfFiles = 100000;
        var stepCount = 1000;
        for (var i = 0; i < nrOfFiles; i++)
        {
            if (i % stepCount == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Creating files {i}-{i+stepCount-1}" );
            }
            var filename = Path.Combine(outDirectory, $"{i}.pdf");
            using (var dataTable = CreateDataTable(rowData))
            {
                pdfModule.CreateFile(filename, dataTable);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Done, created {nrOfFiles} files");
    }
}
```

For the rest, I am not sure my environment matches with yours, but it ran consistently (sparring the notifications of `ITextSharp` that I didn't have a valid AGPL license ^_^) and I was running it under Linux with the Rider IDE

Comment: _"sparring the notifications of ITextSharp that I didn't have a valid AGPL license ^_^"_ - that you either don't have a commercial license, or are otherwise running under the AGPL license. There's a way to turn off that AGPL message when you really are using iText in an AGPL environment, but I don't know how from the top of my mind.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Yeah, it gives some good information inside the console, so theoretically I think I could point to this sourcecode and ask for an AGPL license, but I really only used it to answer this question, so for me it was good enough :)